# Stuck GhostScript processes, how to debug?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ghostscript

Having a problem with Ghostscript processes that don't end. This does not happen often, probably once every 3 weeks we see this issue with 1-3 processes. Running CentOS 6.4 on a VPS from Rackspace. We use PrinceXML to generate PDFs which uses GhostScript to handle fonts.

Here's an image of top:

[image]

As you can see those two processes are using a lot of resources, I haven't killed them yet in hopes someone can help me diagnose. I'm a developer not a server admin so I have a basic knowledge of *nix but no clue on how to fix this.

Installed strace and ran it on each process with the following command:
strace -p 20619 -s 80 -o gs.txt

Left it for 5m, gs.txt is empty?

Comment: I usually use "strace -f -p pid". If you don't see anything there, I believe that the process is just processing your input. You could generate a coredump to examine the process. 

Have you tried to change the rendering options eg remove INTERPOLATE if it used?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan did you ever find the issue with these GS processes?  I have been experiencing the same and am trying to find a solution other than the "kill after 5 minutes" proposal from one of your other threads on the subject. :)