# Bash script to kill specific process running longer than 5m

Tags: centos, bash, process, kill

Hi I'm looking for a BASH script for CentOS 6.5 that kills a processes by name that's been running longer than 5 minutes. I asked this question before and received a response that doesn't work under CentOS because killall doesn't have --older-than. I'm looking for an equivalent to that that will work under CentOS.

That post is here: [Kill any GS process that's been running for over 5m on CentOS 6.5](https://serverfault.com/questions/636406/kill-any-gs-process-thats-been-running-for-over-5m-on-centos-6-5)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just start the original process with [timeout](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout).

Comment: @Zoredache I've never even *seen* that before!

Answer (score 3):

I really suggest finding the root cause of **[this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/636406/kill-any-gs-process-thats-been-running-for-over-5m-on-centos-6-5)** (or [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/599525/stuck-ghostscript-processes-how-to-debug) or *[this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/752951/how-to-upgrade-ghostscript-to-9-x-on-centos-6-5)*).

A `killall` is a heavy-handed approach to process management, and your real issue is probably an application or resource problem.

Can you outline what you've tried so far? The types of things I would check are:

- System vitals at the time these runaway Ghostscript processes occur: RAM? CPU?
- Make sure the system this is running on has enough memory and doesn't have major contention for other resources.
- Is this a physical or virtual server?
- Talk to the vendor. There's a [community and some level of support](http://www.princexml.com/forum/) around PrinceXML.
- A possible `strace` of the affected PIDs and Parent PIDs.
- Are all of the requisite fonts installed?
- Try logging the times that this happens to see if there's a correlation between the hang and other system events.
- If you don't have historical and granular monitoring, you should. You could even try something like [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com) to try to get a picture of what is happening or happened at a given time.
- Check apache settings. It looks as though Ghostscript is being spawned by the apache user. Are there any limits or server settings that should be examined here?

Based on [your output from an earlier question](https://serverfault.com/questions/599525/stuck-ghostscript-processes-how-to-debug), it looks like you've only allocated 1 Gigabyte of RAM to this system and possibly only have a single CPU - no swap either...

[image]

If all else fails, you can write a script that can clean up old or stalled processes... or just compile a version of `killall` that supports the `--older-than` flag.

Comment: I'm a programmer not a sysadmin so I'll be honest I'm completely clueless on how to fix this the right way. Are you interested in taking a contract job to diagnose this for us? PM me your email if you're interested.

Comment: @Jonathan Well, how often does this happen? Can you increase RAM on your Rackspace instance? Is it just one CPU?

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this be ok?

```
#!/bin/bash

PROC_NAME=my_proc_name

# Get all PIDs for process name
procs=(`ps aux | grep  $PROC_NAME | awk '{print $2}'`)

# for each PID in PIDs array
for pid in $procs; do
    # get elapsed time in form mm:ss and remove ":" character
    # to make it easier to parse time 
    time=(`ps -o etime $pid | sed -e 's/[:-]/ /g'`)
    # get minutes from time
    min=${time[1]}
    # if proces runs 5 minutes then kill it
    if [ "$min" -gt "5" ]; then
        kill -9 $pid
    fi
done;
```

Of course it should be executed by cron or something like that to check processes periodically.